# Issue while fetching Imagesg from RSS feed

Tags: java, android, rss

I'm trying to get the RSS feed into my android application, I am retrieving feeds like title, description and link of feed but not able to get image for particular feed.

The fallowing is my DefaultXmlHandler class. please go through and help me out.

```
 public class XmlHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private RssFeedStructure feedStr = new RssFeedStructure();
private List<RssFeedStructure> rssList = new ArrayList<RssFeedStructure>();

private int articlesAdded = 0;

// Number of articles to download
private static final int ARTICLES_LIMIT = 15;

StringBuffer chars = new StringBuffer();

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) {
    chars = new StringBuffer();

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("media:content"))

    {
        if(!atts.getValue("url").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
            feedStr.setImgLink(atts.getValue("url").toString());
        }
        else{
            feedStr.setImgLink("");
        }
    }

}
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
    {
        feedStr.setTitle(chars.toString());
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
    {

        feedStr.setDescription(chars.toString());
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate"))
    {

        feedStr.setPubDate(chars.toString());
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("encoded"))
    {

        feedStr.setEncodedContent(chars.toString());
    }
    else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("media:content"))

    {

    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
    {
        try {
            feedStr.setUrl(new URL(chars.toString()));
        }catch (Exception e){}

    }
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
        rssList.add(feedStr);

        feedStr = new RssFeedStructure();
        articlesAdded++;
        if (articlesAdded >= ARTICLES_LIMIT)
        {
            throw new SAXException();
        }
    }
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    chars.append(new String(ch, start, length));
}


public List<RssFeedStructure> getLatestArticles(String feedUrl) {
    URL url = null;
    try {

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        url = new URL(feedUrl);
        xr.setContentHandler(this);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } catch (SAXException e) {

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

    }

    return rssList;
}
```

}

Comment: Please some bady help me out....

Comment: What does your feed look like? We need to know what type of data you're dealing with here.

Comment: Thanks for responding  Pkmmte. Any Standard feed that containing image,title and link of news. I am getting all other expect image of feed. @ Pkmmte